# Enable local scripts and flash in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm running an old little app which runs in the browser from local files, and I keep getting the, "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or Activex controls that could access your computer" message.

Is there a registry setting or something I can tweak to allow it to run automatically?

I'm aware of [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx) but it is not practical in this case (neither is running in Firefox, unfortunately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the local file system (file://*) to the safe websites in the security settings.

Comment: Doesn't let me add "file://*" or variations as a trusted site.

Answer (score 0):

It's in Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer.